Allow user to add image to the widget in Flutter
I am making an app in Flutter, and I want the user to be able to add a picture to a widget containing their user profile.
I was thinking of using image_picker but how should I write the code so the image can be retrieved?
Also, how can I create more posts under the initial/first post? (like the widget with all that data to be duplicated but with the new data added by the user)
This is my code currently:
    class WorkoutContentPage extends StatefulWidget {
      const WorkoutContentPage({super.key});
    
      @override
      WorkoutContentPageState createState() => WorkoutContentPageState();
    }
    
    class WorkoutContentPageState extends State<WorkoutContentPage> {
      final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
      Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map>>? stream;
      String? userId;
      String? nameprogram;
      String? typeprogram;
      String? typeequipment;
      TextEditingController nameprogramController = TextEditingController();
      TextEditingController typeprogramController = TextEditingController();
      TextEditingController typeequipmentController = TextEditingController();
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        userId = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
        FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection("Users")
            .doc(userId)
            .get()
            .then((value) {
          var data = value.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
          nameprogram = data["nameprogram"];
          typeprogram = data["typeprogram"];
          typeequipment = data["typeequipment"];
    
          // Populate TextEditingControllers with existing data
          nameprogramController.text = nameprogram ?? '';
          typeprogramController.text = typeprogram ?? '';
          typeequipmentController.text = typeequipment ?? '';
        });
        super.initState();
      }
    
      @override
      void dispose() {
        // Dispose of the controllers when the widget is disposed
        nameprogramController.dispose();
        typeprogramController.dispose();
        typeequipmentController.dispose();
        super.dispose();
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(
              'Workout Content',
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white),
            ),
            centerTitle: true,
            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          ),
          body: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: 30,
                ),
                Center(
                    child: Column(children: [
                  Text(
                    'Add details about your entire workout program',
                    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 15),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  TextField(
                    controller: nameprogramController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "Name of the program",
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18),
                          borderSide: BorderSide.none),
                      fillColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1),
                      filled: true,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  TextField(
                    controller: typeprogramController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "Type of program(ex: strength, cardio, yoga",
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18),
                          borderSide: BorderSide.none),
                      fillColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1),
                      filled: true,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  TextField(
                    controller: typeequipmentController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "Type of equipment used",
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18),
                          borderSide: BorderSide.none),
                      fillColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1),
                      filled: true,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    width: 250,
                    height: 70,
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => WorkoutContentPage()),
                        );
                      },
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        shape: const StadiumBorder(),
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16),
                        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                      ),
                      child: const Text(
                        "+Add photo/video for cover",
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  Text(
                      'We suggest you to do a short video of 10-15 sec with some exercise that your program has so the user can get an idea of what to expect'),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 40,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    width: 250,
                    height: 70,
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => WorkoutContentPage()),
                        );
                      },
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        shape: const StadiumBorder(),
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16),
                        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                      ),
                      child: const Text(
                        "Set price",
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ]))
              ],
            ),
          ),
          bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
            color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 240, 240, 240),
            child: Container(
              width: 50,
              child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Users").doc(userId).set({
                      "nameprogram": nameprogramController.text,
                      "typeprogram": typeprogramController.text,
                      "typeequipment": typeequipmentController.text,
                    }).then((_) {
                      // Navigate to the user profile page
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => UserProfilePage()),
                      );
                    });
                  },
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    shape: const StadiumBorder(),
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16),
                    backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                  ),
                  child: Text(
                    'Continue',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  )),
            ),
          ),
        );
        // ignore: dead_code
      }
    
      void _alertNoText(BuildContext context) {
        Alert(
          context: context,
          type: AlertType.warning,
          title: "Post",
          desc: "You have not written any text",
          buttons: [
            DialogButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
              width: 120,
              child: const Text(
                "Close",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ).show();
      }
    }
    
    class UserProfilePage extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        final userId = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
    
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('User Profile'),
          ),
          body: FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
            future:
                FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Users").doc(userId).get(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              }
    
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return const Center(child: Text('Error fetching data'));
              }
    
              if (!snapshot.hasData || !snapshot.data!.exists) {
                return const Center(child: Text('No data found'));
              }
    
              final data = snapshot.data!.data()!;
              final nameprogram = data["nameprogram"];
              final typeprogram = data["typeprogram"];
              final typeequipment = data["typeequipment"];
    
              return Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left: 10, right: 10),
                  child: Container(
                      height: 135,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.90,
                      decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius:
                                new BorderRadius.all(new Radius.circular(10))),
                        color: Colors.white,
                        shadows: [
                          BoxShadow(
                            color: Colors.grey.shade400,
                            blurRadius: 5,
                            spreadRadius: 2,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      child: Row(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: [
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 10,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 90,
                          height: 90,
                          child: Image.asset(
                            'assets/applogo.png',
                            fit: BoxFit.contain,
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(width: 10), // space between image & Column
                        Expanded(
                            child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          //  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 25,
                            ),
                            Text('$nameprogram',
                                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 5,
                            ),
                            Text('type: $typeprogram',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    color: Colors.grey)),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 5,
                            ),
                            Text('equipment: $typeequipment',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    color: Colors.grey)),
                          ],
                        )),
                      ])));
            },
          ),
        );
      }
    }

A video of what is currently happening: https://imgur.com/a/JgLLLLe
